# Обучение Assembler

Tags: ассемблер, ide, компилятор

Здравствуйте. Я недавно решил копнуть Assembler (просто посмотреть что это).
И у меня появились вопросы:

1. Обычно для всех языков я применяю один редактор или IDE. Но на многих сайтах я вижу огрооомный (для меня) список программ для программирования на Assembler. Более менее стандартный список со всех сайтов - Hiew , FAR , MASM. Если не трудно объясните зачем они нужны? Во всех есть свои редакторы. Но авторы статей упорно стараются работать сразу через все :D (что для меня к примеру достаточно не удобно).
2. Второй вопрос выходит из первого. Есть ли какая нибудь единая IDE или редактор для Asm? Что бы не отвлекаться на извращения с переключением редактора :).
3. Мой (как сказано на одном сайте) Си-подобный :) мозг не привык к асму и книги мне идут трудно. Подскажите какие нить туториалы для чайников или лёгкие книги для подобной категории людей ^_^.
4. Где сейчас в основном применяется ассемблер? :)

Заранее спасибо

ps. С ассемблером не знаком даже на минимальном уровне - не пинайте сильно :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Редактор используется для редактирования, транслятор для трансляции, отладчик для отладки, а IDE (integrated development environment) с большим или меньшим успехом пытается их все объединять. (Да и не только их -- ведение проектов, контроль версий и пр.). Не знаю,  кто такой Hiew, Far -- файловый менеджер, в котором есть достаточно сносный редактор (по крайней мере не хуже notepad'а). Masm -- ассемблер от MS (Линкер вроде там же). Есть масса других ассемблеров. Борландовский ТASM вроде шёл со средой, но там только 16-бит режимы (для 8086 и выше. В виндах-линуксах работают под эмуляцией dos). Есть as -- gnu assembler (со своим синтаксисом). Новая фанатская разработка -- fasm (flat asm).
2. Наверное есть. Есть универсальный вариант --  Emacs/XEmacs. Там много чего есть. И даже значительно больше.
3. Си знаете? Отлично. Пишете на Си, транслируете в ассемблер (сначала без оптимизации), смотрите. Заодно и Си узнаете получше.
4. В качестве хобби -- где угодно. "Охота пуще неволи". По необходимости -- программирование микроконтроллеров, правда самых мелких или не самых мелких, но при огромных программах выпуска. Классический пример -- шестиногие pic'и (микрочиповские PIC10F20x). Память: флеш 256 - 512 слов,  RAM -- 16 - 24 байта. Тут ассемблер незаменим. Для программирования более мощных устройств лучше использовать Си.

Comment: >Новая фанатская разработка -- fasm (flat asm).
Версия 1.62 вышла в 2005 году, когда вышла первая версия к сожалению сказать не могу. Так что не такая уж и новая разработка. flat assembler на данный момент по стабильности не уступает тому же masm.

Answer (score 2):

1. Для ассемблера нет одного единственного, утвержденного вышестоящими инстанциями редактора или IDE ;) Из того что было названо: Hiew - шестнадцатеричный редактор, предназначен для правки бинарных файлов, таких как экзешники например. Far - файловый менеждер, упрощенно говоря - что-то вроде проводника, но с двумя панелями и командной строкой ну и своим текстовым редактором. Masm - это один из компиляторов ассемблера, надеюсь для чего он нужен объяснять не нужно:) Все вместе это можно считать IDE :) Лично я пользуюсь Total Commander + SciTE + FASM + HT Editor + IDA + OllyDbg.
2. Из специализированных IDE, могу назвать RadASM.
3. Александр Крупник - Ассемблер. Самоучитель.
4. Кроме хобби, попыток обогнать по качеству кода компилятор ЯВУ, программирования микроконтроллеров, есть еще такая ниша как [реверс-инженеринг](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Обратная разработка).

Comment: Я думал уже не дождусь :D Спасиба =)

Comment: По-моему TASM всё-же такой. Но это dos, 16bit, real mode. Если интересна археология типа bios или dos interrupts, то подойдёт.

Comment: Не вижу кто упомянул TASM, но в защиту TASM могу сказать, что он умеет компилировать и под 32 бит.

Answer (score 0):

Начинающим могу посоветовать [SASM](http://dman95.github.io/SASM/) IDE для разработки на ассемблере NASM. В ней есть хорошая подсветка синтаксиса, отладчик и библиотека макросов ввода-вывода, удобная для новичков.